# Como detectar cadenas de caracteres muy largas en ficheros

Tags: php

Estoy intendando detectar  ficheros con nombres muy largos  y si el fichero tiene  `palabras` muy largas en su contenido.

por ejemplo:

string con palabras normales

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum a
> accumsan risus, at iaculis tellus. Suspendisse commodo, erat ut
> vestibulum pretium, diam nunc gravida nunc, vitae facilisis libero
> purus ut est. Maecenas pellentesque enim erat, quis porttitor magna
> egestas in. Fusce in vulputate felis. Nam ultrices ultricies leo.

String con palabras muy largas:

> psumdolorsitametconsecteturadipiscingelitVestibulumaaccumsanrisusatiaculistellus.
> Suspendissecommodoeratutvestibulum pretiumdiamnuncgravidanuncvitae
> facilisis libero purus ut est. Maecenas pellentesqueenimeratquis
> porttitor magna egestas in. Fusce in vulputate felis. Nam ultrices
> ultricies leo,

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```html
 
 $listadoWeb =  ["public_html/src/documento.txt","public_html/src/nombremuylargoasdasdasdasdasdasdaaasd.txt"];
 
 
 foreach ($listadoWeb as $indice => $fichero) {
     $largo = 0;
     #leo el contenido
     $contenido = file_get_contents($fichero);
     
     #detecto si el nombre del fichero es muy largo
     $ruta = explode("/",$fichero);
     if(strlen( end($ruta))> 40){
          $largo = 1;
          $positivo =["nombre muy largo"];
     }
     
     #detectar string largos en el contenido
     # como lo hago???
   
    if($largo) {
        var_dump($positivo);
        echo $fichero . "<br>";
    }
 }
```

**salida**

> nombre muy largo
> public_html/src/nombremuylargoasdasdasdasdasdasdaaasd.txt